# Can you debug your Android app running in Google Android Emulator with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Can you debug your Android app (created with VS2017) running in Google Android Emulator with Visual Studio 2017?

If you can how do you do that?  I have debugged with the Visual Studio MS Android emulator with no problems but I can't seem to do that with the Google Android emulator.

Comment: I am not familar with your `Google Android Emulator`? Third-part android emulator ? Why not use Visual Studio MS Android emulator?

Comment: I have found with certain code the Visual Studio Android crashes.  But when run on a actual phone it doesn't.  Another example is that I have some code that displays a video and it doesn't display on the Visual Studio Android emulator...but on the phone it displays fine.  Also Microsoft also recommends you use the Google Android emulator.  If you go to Microsoft's webpage: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/   the first thing it says  is that they recommend the Google emulator.

Comment: The Visual Studio Emulator for Android is deprecated, don't use it. It's suggested to use the Google Android Emulator provided directly within the Android SDK. For any differences between emulator and device, you'll have to provide more context as to code you're trying to run and potentially screenshots or screencasts demonstrating the problems. Emulators != Devices as they emulate the behaviors a device has. Certain functionality can be limited, but it's hard to tell with regards to your current question and what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am having a hard time getting the debugger to work with the Android emulator.  With the Visual Studio Android emulator the debugger just worked.  But are there some steps I need to do to get it to work with the Google Android emulator?

Comment: Does VS and AS use same SDK folder?